# Onclick event: Navigate to a page in current tab when clicking browser context menu (in a FF add-on)

Tags: javascript, onclick, firefox-addon

I am building a Firefox Add-on that adds an option to the browser context menu. When users click in the context menu, a specific website should open (in the same tab).

I am sure I oversimplified this process in my code stub below. I am just a beginner trying to make sense of objects and onclick. Questions:

1. Does the below code work?
2. Do I need any special permissions granted in the manifest.json when using onClicked?

FYI: The final Add-on functionality shall be more sophisticated then the described above. The above is just the first problem I need to solve. For simplicity & clarity I am sparing the details for now.

Thanks!

```
browser.menus.create({
id: "openSelection",
title: "Open selection in PhoneTool",
contexts: ["selection"]
});

browser.menus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
if (info.menuItemId == "open-selection") {
onclick="location.href='http://hsv.de/';"
//define action here that should occur when "open-selection" is clicked
}
});
```

I searched here, but previous questions circle around how to *create* browser context menus, but I could not find a question circling around how to navigate to a different page based on a click in the browser context menu.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your questions are:

1. No, your code will not work. It will create a context menu and the menu will show up when you select a text. But with this code, a webpage will not open on click of the menu item.
2. You don't need any additional permission to use the onClicked event.

You should create a tab with the URL of the webpage/website to load that page in the browser.

```
browser.menus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId == "log-selection") {
    browser.tabs.create({
        url: "http://hsv.de/"
    })
  }
});
```

You need the permission ***"tabs"*** to use the Tab API. So you should include it in your manifest.json file.